# How to combine video segments on a server and then stream to web and iphone

Tags: iphone, video, streaming

I am trying to work out a solution to achieve the following:

I have a number of videos ( all same format and dimensions ) that I wish to be able to dynamically combine based on a web front end, and then stream the result.

I need to stream to web ( flash ) as well as iPhone ( http live streaming )

My current thoughts are to take the videos and then combine them with ffmpeg-php on the server, then with the resulting file provide it for viewing either as a progressive or through the use of flash media server / wowza server.

My question is: Are there better ways to handle this.... ( some smarts within wowza or flash media server that could do this for me)

Answer (score 0):

## It will likely be much easier to use some sort of playlist.

For the iOS devices, HTTP Live Streaming readily support such a mechanism with the .m3u8 files.  For the Flash-based players, you could implement something custom or use JW Player which can do such magic.

Working with FFmpeg will be much more complex:

- if your video sources are notably different in size or CODEC parameters, the poor quality and outright failures will happen
- transcoding can easily degrade quality if you are not well versed in such matters.
- dramatically more CPU resources will be required on the server.  Like >10,000% more than a playlist approach, depending.